# Find a $1$-form $ω$ on $\mathbb R^2 −\{(0,0)\}$ such that $ω(X) = 1$ and $ω(Y) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-algebras

[image]

Please ı dont know what I need to do. thus, help me to solve.

Comment: Let $\omega = f\mathrm{d}x + g\mathrm{d}y$, see what conditions $f$ and $g$ must have fulfilled.

Comment: What are the $f$ and $g$ here? Please can you write more clear? I cannot image what you said in my mind. Thank you for help, btw. @ShuhaoCao

Comment: @ShuhaoCao please help me?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a 1-form $\newcommand{\pp}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}\mathrm{d}\xi$, acting on a vector field $\displaystyle\mathbf{v} = v_1 \pp{}{x} +  v_2  \pp{}{y}$ means taking the derivative along the $\mathbf{v}$:
$$
\mathrm{d}\xi(\mathbf{v}) = v_1 \pp{\xi}{x} +  v_2 \pp{\xi}{y}
$$
Hence let $\omega = f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x + g(x,y)\mathrm{d}y$, then 
$$
\omega(\mathbf{X}) = f\mathrm{d}x(\mathbf{X}) + g\mathrm{d}y(\mathbf{X})
=(-fy\pp{x}{x} + fx\pp{x}{y}) + (-gy\pp{y}{x} + gx\pp{y}{y}) = -fy + gx = 1
$$
Similarly we have:
$$
\omega(\mathbf{Y}) = fx + gy = 0
$$
Then solving the following linear system for $f$ and $g$ will give you the answer:
$$
\begin{cases}
-yf(x,y) + xg(x,y) = 1
\\
xf(x,y) + yg(x,y) = 0
\end{cases}
$$
and we have:
$$
\omega = \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2} \mathrm{d}x +  \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \mathrm{d}y 
$$

Comment: Yayy!! Thank you for help:) really this is a so instructive solution. I have learnt well :))